# Dapper nested list query

Tags: list, nested, dapper

I have 3 POCO classes as below;

Continent has many ContinentPart

Continent has many Country

Country has many City

I want to get Continens with ContinentParts, Countries and Cities

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_conf["ConnectionStrings:WorkConStr"]))
            {
                string query = @"SELECT * FROM Continent as c
                                LEFT JOIN ContinentPart as cp ON c.ContinentId=cp.ContinentId
                                LEFT JOIN Country as co ON c.ContinentId=co.ContinentId
                                LEFT JOIN City ci ON co.CountryId=ci.CountryId
                                ORDER BY c.RecDate DESC";

                var continentDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Continent>();
                var list = db.Query<Continent, ContinentPart, Country, City, Continent>(
                    query,
                    map: (continent, continentPart, country, city) =>
                     {
                         Continent m;
                         if (!continentDictionary.TryGetValue(continent.ContinentId, out m))
                         {
                             continentDictionary.Add(continent.ContinentId, m = continent);
                         }
                         if (m.ContinentParts == null)
                             m.ContinentParts = new List<ContinentPart>();
                         m.ContinentParts.Add(continentPart);
                         if (m.Countries == null)
                             m.Countries = new List<Country>();
                         m.Countries.Add(country);
                         foreach (var h in m.Countries)
                         {
                             if (h.Cities == null)
                                 h.Cities = new List<City>();
                             h.Cities.Add(city);
                         }
                         return m;
                     },
                    param: new { },
                    splitOn: "")
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
                return list;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. You can use Multiple Resultsets feature:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172

Or, another option, better in my opinion, is to return the joined result as a JSON, for example with a query like the following:

```
select 
    continents.continent_id,
    continents.continent,
    countries.country_id,
    countries.country,
    cities.city_id,
    cities.city 
from 
    dbo.Continent continents
inner join 
    dbo.Country countries on continents.continent_id = countries.continent_id
inner join
    dbo.City cities on countries.country_id = cities.country_id
for 
    json auto
```

that returns a JSON like this:

```
{
    "continent_id": 1,
    "continent": "Africa",
    "countries":
    [
        {
            "country_id": 1,
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "cities":           
            [   
                {
                    "city_id": 1,
                    "city": "Lagos"
                }, {
                    "city_id": 2,
                    "city": "Abuja"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and that can then be turned into a complex object using Custom Type Handling:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-type-handling-4b447b97c620

Links are to articles I've wrote on the subject.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response, i tried first option and it worked. Second one is little bit complicated. may be i will try it later. One more question; what about the performance? For example i have invoice table and it has details in many tables on database. it has 100K row. The first approach is performant in that scenerio?

Comment: Here's an example of how to return the whole set of continents, country and cities as one big json document:

SQL Code to setup the sample:
https://gist.github.com/yorek/a46c837aacf00d9c58a4f9e8146e7cc0

.NET Core 2.0 C# Code:
https://gist.github.com/yorek/587616768e2a12054403b68762682ace

Comment: Beside the sample, I would strongly advise against returning 100K rows in just one single pass. Do you really have to load all that data in memory? Performance will likely suffer. It's way better to load only the continent (or country or city) that you need.

Comment: Hi,I know you have important jobs to do :) but thank you very much for answers. I agree with you about performance issue if I get 100K rows in one pass. But my scenario about reporting. I use 3rd party grid for report results and user sort or group report results in memory than send to excel. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @adiii4 I guess you mean a recursive CTE, right? If yes it should. Never tried to be hones but I don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I am trying to create a file tree structure.